How to replace a letter in a LaTeX document
I want to write a text using "w" but the output should be "ë". How to do this when using, say, the overleaf editor?
I have tried some codes I could find online such as
\catcode ... 
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter ...

but they don't work. Any ideas?

You've tagged this pdftex.  Are you open to using Lua?  This doesn't depend on Overleaf, so you shouldn't have tagged it that.  Are you doing this because you have some text where ë occurs a lot, and you don't want to use an official way?  How long is this text?  Which ways of typing ë have you tried and not liked?

Have you considered using latex syntax for the "ë", and then using ctrl-f to replace all w's with the syntax for "ë"? If it is a multi-file document, you'd have to do this for each file. Overleaf lets you replace all with ctrl-f easily. You could also write the letter in a short macro, so it is easy to type.

Welcome to TeX.SE. I've taken the liberty of editing the title of your query to remove the words "overleaf" and "compiler", as the substance of the query would not appear to be related to these words. Feel free to revert.

@Teepeemm I'm new to using this website and Overleaf, so I'm not familiar with a lot of things, I will remove the hashtags if that is incorrect, thanks for the comment. Regarding the question originally asked, I am basically using Overleaf to write some math documents in my native tongue, where the letter ë is very common (1 in 3 words hast at least one ë). Since it's about math, it is not just plain text. I use a lot of commands and some contain "w", which interferes with the replacing methods I tried, and basically the code doesn't work for "w".

@Jasper. Thank you for your advice using ctrl+f, this seems more efficient than the method I'm using currently. Do you know if there is a way to 'replace all' but for text only? Since some commands do have w, I don't want to replace those. Replacing each w manually is still helpful, thank you.

@overleaf_latex are you sure that this isn't an incorrect keyboard language setting?

@Jasper I have an English keyboard (hardware) and I actually have downloaded a keyboard layout containing the letter ë. However, most English keyboard keys don't match the character, when switching to the other keyboard layout containing ë. That is confusing to write, especially in math mode. Until now, I've been either constantly switching between keyboard layout, or using the Copy Paste function whenever there is an ë. So I was looking for an efficient way to write the code. (Did I understand your question correctly?)

@overleaf_latex Cool, I was just making sure that it wasn't the wrong one. For example, there are two main keyboard languages where I am from and they cause some keys to output different characters. for your case, I would personally define it in a small macro, \newcommand{myE}{ë}

@Jasper Thanks, that's also helpful.

If you have a font editor (and know how to use it): Possibly change the w glyph, so it prints as ë. As far as TeX code is concerned, it is still w. But it looks like ë in print.

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter can only be used for UTF-8 characters that are not in the ASCII range. If w were made active and defined by such a command then all tex commands containing w would break.
\newcommand would parse as \neëcommand
Within a local group where you know this is safe and there are no conflicting w then
\catcode`\w=\active
\def w{ë}

will work. But this could ony be used in highly restricted environments.

Thank you for your answer. Now at least I understand why this method doesn't work. So I suppose any other method won't work as long as the letter to be replaced is "w" or any other letter contained in commands for that matter, right?

@overleaf_latex probably there is a way to do whatever you want to do but it is hard to suggest anything as what you suggest is basically  unimplementable in tex. I suspect there is a use case that does have a solution. One thing to bear in mind is that tex never has more than a line of characters in memory it reads line by line expanding macros until it has accumulated a paragraph then it typesets that possibly outputs a page, then that has gone. so something like change w to ë which could be done with a single replace string in sed or perl or python or anything, is kind of tricky for tex.
